# Loading a Form with out its instance

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi all I would like to get the form loaded from the `database`, I am storing my form name as `Form1` in my DB. Now I would like to get this form name on the other form button click event I tried as follows by storing the form name in a string but I am unable to load the form can some one help me

```
string strFromName="Form1";
Type type = Type.GetType(strFromName); // Null reference is coming here
Form form = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: It requires [*assembly-qualified name of the type to get.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx)

Comment: Have you read documentation of [Type.GetType(string typename)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) method and what kind of parameter it expecting? I guess no!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to supply the fully qualified name of the form ("TopNamespace.SubNameSpace.Form1") or if the form class is residing in an Assembly other than the calling you have to supply an [AssemblyQualifiedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx) ("TopNamespace.SubNameSpace.Form1,MyAssembly").

See the [Type.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) documentation for the details.

Answer (score 1):

Get all types from assembly and compare instances with your string "Form1" by name after you can get instatnce type